# Inconsistency in the analysis of independent mesh sets and cut sets related to an electrical network

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

From the observation of the set of independent meshes and the set of cuts obtained from the Digraph of an electrical network, the two corresponding matrices alpha and beta are obtained. the product of the alpha matrix by the transpose of the beta matrix must be zero. however it is not (see 1 circle in red). Is there anyone who can find the error? I thank those who will answer me.
[image]

Comment: I couldn't find any error. Not in the alpha matrix nor in the cut matrix. I made the multiplication and the 1 was there. However, I don't know the background of the multiplication being zero (I assume it is related to topology properties of graphs).

Comment: A rule for determining the cuts in the graph has been broken, namely: a cut must intersect each branch only once, which does not happen for T4.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the "construction" of the two matrices. It must be performed by analyzing the graph with the meshes for the first, and the one with the cuts for the second matrix. That is, the alpha elements are determined in the following way: if the mesh current is congruent with that of the branch, 1 is placed in the corresponding matrix element (row = mesh, column = branch) otherwise -1 if it is discordant, and 0 if the branch is not part of the mesh. As far as the beta matrix is concerned, we must consider the cuts (which are Gauss surfaces that cut the network). Each cut corresponds to a branch of the tree,  which is part of the graph. Each cut is attributed the same direction as the branch to which it corresponds. The beta_t matrix is made up of as many rows as there are cuts, and as many columns as there are branches. A 1 is assigned to each element of this matrix if the direction of the branch agrees with that of the cut. -1 if it is discordant, 0 if the branch is not part of the cut.
The correct analysis is shown below:[image]